# django / AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update' - Update record in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am newbie in django . Need to update database records with values . two queryset populate with filter and database list function and merged both of them in list now i want to update database with emp id and emp name also display result in given html file with updated record database . I am getting below error while trying to update database with merged queryset result in list .

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'

```
    views.py
    
    django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from .forms import requestrecord
    from .models import storetest
    from django.db import transaction
    from itertools import chain
    
    
    def requestdetail(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            formrequest = requestrecord(request.POST)
            if formrequest.is_valid():
                feid = formrequest.cleaned_data['EID']
                femp_name = formrequest.cleaned_data['EMP_NAME']
                fstate = formrequest.cleaned_data['STATE']
                fstore_count = formrequest.cleaned_data['No_Of_Store_id_Assigned']
                data = []
                data1 = []
                data2 = []
                if fstate == "AAA":
                    data1 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate).filter(CITY='AAADDD')[:fstore_count]
                    data2 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate).filter(CITY='AAAEEE')[:fstore_count]       
                    data = list(chain(data1, data2))
                    data = data.update(EID=feid, EMP_NAME=femp_name)
                    data.save()                 
                elif fstate == "BBB":
                    data1 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate).filter(CITY='BBBFFF')[:fstore_count]
                    data2 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate).filter(CITY='BBBGGG')[:fstore_count]
                    data = list(chain(data1, data2))
                    data = data.update(EID=feid, EMP_NAME=femp_name)
                    data.save()             
                else:
                    "No Selection"
                print(data)            
                print(fpid)
                print(fproj_name) 
                print(fcountry_did_request) 
                print(fstore_count)
                #formtorequest.save()
                formrequest = requestrecord()
        else:
            formrequest = requestrecord()
        return render(request,'Request-Record.html',{'form':formrequest})
```

Comment: You can not call `.update` on a list, only on a `QuerySet`, due to the `chain` and `list`, that is thus no longer possible.

Comment: Use `data1.update(EID=feid, EMP_NAME=femp_name)` and `data2.update(EID=feid, EMP_NAME=femp_name)` instead. Furthermore a queryset/list has no `.save` function either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list(chain(data1, data2))` produces a `list`, a `list` has no `.update(…)` method. Using `chain` will result in an iterable without a `.update(…)` either. Nor has it a `.save()` method either. You can update the two querysets individually:

```
if fstate == 'AAA':
    data1 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate, CITY='AAADDD')[:fstore_count]
    data2 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate, CITY='AAAEEE')[:fstore_count]
    storetest.objects.filter(
        pk__in=[s.pk for s in chain(data1, data2)]
    ).update(EID=feid, EMP_NAME=femp_name)
elif fstate == 'BBB':
    data1 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate, CITY='BBBFFF')[:fstore_count]
    data2 = storetest.objects.filter(STATE=fstate, CITY='BBBGGG')[:fstore_count]
    storetest.objects.filter(
        pk__in=[s.pk for s in chain(data1, data2)]
    ).update(EID=feid, EMP_NAME=femp_name)
```

Comment: Wow great your solution works perfectly , please help  me to display updated record in same view,py file mentioned html file

Comment: @djman87: a view that makes updates should be done with a POST, PATCH, etc. but normally it is followed by a redirect to implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get